# How to find and format an address from a cell using a VBA function and Google Places API?

Tags: excel, vba, function, google-places-api

To make sure an address is always formatted the same way (which I will use in another VBA Sub), I'm trying to use the Google Places API in combination with a created VBA function.

The query works in the browser but not from the created function.

The working API (temporary API-key added) with a random address: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?fields=formatted_address%2Cname%2Crating%2Copening_hours%2Cgeometry&input=Coendersweg%202&inputtype=textquery&key=API_KEY

It gives "Formatted_Address" which I'd like to show up as the result of the function.

Example result of random address:

> Coendersweg 2, 9722GE Groningen / [Streetname number, Zipcode City]

If it's possible to make resulting address have the zip code (9722 GE) formatted as "9722GE" and the country ", Nederland" not show up that would be even better.

VBA code I have so far:

```vb
Function FindAddress(address, APIKEY)
Dim strURL As String
strURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/" & _
  "json?fields=formatted_address%2Cname%2Crating%2Copening_hours%2Cgeometry&input=" _
  & address & "&inputtype=textquery&key=" & APIKEY

Set httpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
With httpReq
    .Open "GET", strURL, False
    .Send
End With

Dim Response As String
Response = httpReq.ResponseText

Dim parsed As Dictionary
Set parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(Response)
Dim FoundAddress As String

FoundAddress = (formatted_address)

FindAddress = FoundAddress
```

I've the "JsonConverter.bas" from https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON as a module inside my VBA.

Most of the code is borrowed from the following YouTube video. I made some tweaks to work with Google Places API instead of Google Directions API:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_P2lj4yHNu4.

Comment: have you tried inspecting `parsed` object? Maybe try `FoundAddress = parsed("candidates")(1)("formatted_address")`

Comment: This seems to make the function as intended, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method that will return the `formatted_address` field.  You can return other fields if you prefer -- the modifications should be obvious.

Note that I used early binding, but you can use late binding if you prefer.

Run against your input, => `Coendersweg 2, 9722 GE Groningen, Netherlands`

```
Option Explicit
Function getAddress(S As String)
    Const API As String = "key=YOUR_API_KEY"
    Const sURL1 As String = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?fields=formatted_address"
    Const sURL2 As String = "input="
    Const sURL3 As String = "inputtype=textquery"
    Dim sAddr As String
    Dim sURL() As String
    Dim sLocation As String
    Dim xhrRequest As XMLHTTP60

Dim strJSON As String, JSON As Object

sAddr = Replace(S, " ", "%20")

'Many ways to create the URL to send
ReDim sURL(3)
    sURL(0) = sURL1
    sURL(1) = sURL2 & sAddr
    sURL(2) = sURL3
    sURL(3) = API
Set xhrRequest = New XMLHTTP60
With xhrRequest
    .Open "Get", Join(sURL, "&"), False
    .Send
    strJSON = .ResponseText
End With

Set JSON = ParseJson(strJSON)
If Not JSON("status") = "OK" Then
    MsgBox "Status message: " & JSON("status")
    Exit Function
End If

'might need to check if more than one candidate is returned
getAddress = JSON("candidates")(1)("formatted_address")

End Function
```

If you want to have the format different from what is shown, I suggest you use the `Places` api to return the `place_id`.  You can then feed that value into the `Place Details` to return the `address_components` and format the address however you prefer.

Comment: Out of curiosity I'm trying your solution, but it is giving me a compilation error and pointing to the "Dim xhrRequest As XMLHTTP60" part in your code. I suspect this is because I've not got a needed reference enabled. Which reference is needed for that part to function?

Comment: @Rvok Microsoft XML, v6.0

Comment: @milo5m Thank you, that seems to make the code work.